# Is separate graphic card is required or integrated GC will work for Selenium automation with Java?

Tags: selenium

Is separate graphic card is required or integrated GC will work for Selenium automation with Java ?
Also plz suggest other configuration for Selenium automation with Java

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: How does that graphics card related to Selenium? Obviously Selenium works with a browser which uses a graphics card, but you don't need any special card for it.